# rewriting the GetHashCode32(string s) method in C

Tags: c#, c, hashcode

Here is the code of GetHashCode32 method in C#:

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static unsafe int GetHashCode32(this string s)
    {
        fixed (char* str = s.ToCharArray())
        {
            char* chPtr = str;
            int num = 0x15051505;
            int num2 = num;
            int* numPtr = (int*)chPtr;
            for (int i = s.Length; i > 0; i -= 4)
            {
                num = ( ( (num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                if (i <= 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                num2 = ( ( (num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1];
                numPtr += 2;
            }
            return (num + (num2 * 0x5d588b65));
        }
    }
}
```

and I rewrite this method in language C, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main()           
{                  
    char    str[320+1];      
    memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
    int     i;              
    scanf("%s", str);

    char *chPtr = str;
    int num = 0x15051505;
    int num2 = num;
    int *numPtr = (int*)chPtr;

    for (i = strlen(str); i > 0; i -= 4) {
        num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
        if (i <= 2)
        {       
            break;
        }                 
        num2 = ( ( (num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1];
        numPtr += 2;
    } 
    printf("hash code: %d\n", num + (num2 * 0x5d588b65));
    return 0;
}
```

**the c code is complied in -m32 mode.**
but there are different output for these two functions

when input is "354707043566597"

my c code output is 637077169 while it supposed to be -1744455423 in GetHashCode32().

the GetHashCode32 is the library method of C#. so It is right. but I don't know what's wrongwith my C code. 
thanks!

Comment: That `i <= 2` is suspicious; are you sure it's right?  The `>>` operator might be an arithmetic shift in C, too. I don't know what C# says about that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a few reasons why it might be different:

Firstly, `0x15051505` == `0b10101000001010001010100000101` which, if you count it, is 29 bits long. Left-shifting that by 5 will produce undefined behaviour according to the C standard, assuming `sizeof(int) <= 4`.

Secondly, this line:

```
int *numPtr = (int*)chPtr;
```

Is likely mucking things up in the C version (I don't know how C# treats pointers, so I can't say there). When you do `numPtr += 2;`, this is completely different when treating it as a `char*` as opposed to an `int*` (one will move it by 2 bytes, the other by `2 * sizeof(int)` bytes. Hence you're actually dereferencing memory that is outside the range of the string (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`), again causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly. I notice your second point too. and I find that in C#, a char is two bytes actually.

Comment: Actually, In C#, a char is 2Bytes. so the loop is correct. :-)

Answer (score 0):

C char is 1 byte and it is signed, C# char is 2 byte and in C# the first byte is unsigned.

This means that if you have a string in memory and use a 4-byte int poitner to access that memory, you get 4 chars in C into one int, but only 2 chars in C# into one int. So this can never produce the same result.

**How to fix:** Use data type wchar_t in C, it should be more close to C#'s char. You can use `wscanf` to read from console directly to `wchar_t` buffer.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the original algorithm reads UTF-16 (Unicode) strings from memory, two at a time.

The expected data is padded with zeroes:

```
0x00350033 (numPtr[0]) lp0: "35"
0x00370034 (numPtr[1])      "47"
0x00370030 (numPtr[0]) lp1: "07"
0x00340030 (numPtr[1])      "04"
0x00350033 (numPtr[0]) lp2: "35"
0x00360036 (numPtr[1])      "66"
0x00390035 (numPtr[0]) lp3: "59"
0x00000037 (numPtr[1])      "7"
```

The data supplied in C is different (and incorrect):

```
0x37343533 (numPtr[0]) lp0: "3547"
0x34303730 (numPtr[1])      "0704"
0x36363533 (numPtr[0]) lp1: "3566"
0x00373935 (numPtr[1])      "597"
0x00000000 (numPtr[0]) lp2: ""
0x00000000 (numPtr[1])      ""
0x00000000 (numPtr[0]) lp3: ""
0x00000000 (numPtr[1])      ""
```

One quick solution is to cast `numPtr` to `char` (instead of `int`), and construct the expected format manually to retain hash compatibility. Keep in mind the native GetHashCode is not even fully deterministic--Visual Studio and Mono produce different results for same input.

Comment: @downvoter, Is there a problem with my answer? Leave a comment and I will fix it. I tried my best to investigate the cause of the difference in output, and offered a potential solution. But your downvote tells me naught.